# How does a variable frequency drive reduce the energy consumption of a motor?

Tags: power, current, frequency, induction-motor

If the relationship between frequency and current is inversed as answered in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36778/relationship-between-frequency-and-current), how does reducing the supply frequency reduce the energy consumption of a motor?

Answer (score 3):

The referenced question is not about variable frequency drives.

A VFD does not reduce the energy consumption of a motor. The energy consumption of an AC motor is mostly determined by the mechanical energy required to drive the load. The efficiency of the motor is also a factor.

When VFDs are used to reduce energy consumption, they are used to operate the driven process more efficiently. For example, if the flow of air or water from a fan or pump is reduced by restricting the flow by partially closing dampers or valves, energy can be saved by reducing the speed instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is presumed that the question relates to reduction in energy consumption when a VFD is used for speed control instead of a mechanical speed control device e.g. a PIV drive.

With a VFD-controlled induction motor:

1. Below the rated speed, constant V/f control or constant flux control is used . Hence with increasing power and speed, torque remains constant at its rated value till the rated power and speed are attained.
2. Beyond the rated speed, constant voltage control is used. The power remains constant at its rated value as the speed increases and the torque drops.

[image]

Hence the energy consumption, of a VFD-controlled motor, would remain constant at its rated speed and beyond but progressively decrease with decreasing speed, below rated speed.

On the other hand, the energy consumption of a PIV drive-controlled motor, being the same at all speeds, would be higher.